# I can't go into sculpt mode if i don't have the original cube

Tags: sculpt

I made a model, and was gonna finish it off in sculpt mode, but for some reason, even if I select the thing before going to the sculpt tab, the sculpting options don't go on the left and I can't sculpt. What do I do?

Comment: what do you mean by " the sculpting options don't go on the left"? Are the icons missing?

Comment: Hello, maybe you mistakenly hid the tools. Make them appear with shortcut "T"